# How to get the status of each string in each page that is assigned to the fragment?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    //Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getContext(), R.anim.fade);

    sectionlabeltextview = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
    sectionlabeltextview.setText(getArguments().getString("text"));
    sectionlabeltextview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    sectionlabeltextview.setTextSize(25);
    sectionlabel_text = (String) sectionlabeltextview.getText();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),sectionlabel_text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e("sectionlabel_text",sectionlabel_text);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref=getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("catch_text",sectionlabel_text);
    editor.commit();

    //sectionlabeltextview.startAnimation(animation);
    //sectionlabeltextview.setGravity();

    return rootView;
}
```

Here the values of sectionlabel_text and toast message are getting differed, though both are in the same function.Please try to give the solution?

Comment: Show us the values you are getting

Comment: Thank you for responding Mr.SoulRayder.
For suppose when I am in page0, toast is displaying page1 message.When I swipe from right to left, container is getting set with page1 message. But Toast is displaying page2 message.Dont know why it is happening?